# mdsync runs constantly keeping Mac awake

Tags: time-machine

The mdsync process runs incessantly and prevents the Mac from sleeping.  I currently have 4 SSD drives attached via USB to my Mac as Time Machine backup storage.  Previously mdsync would run quickly on the SSD drives then terminate, but now it seems to run for periods of time that could be measured in days.  Because mdsync prevents the Mac from sleeping, this effectively keeps my Mac on continuously.

This mdsync problem has been impacting me for years.  I used to use a NAS for Time Machine storage, but mdsync would run for 24+ hours after each backup.  This would keep both the Mac and the NAS running around the clock so I stopped backing up to the NAS over a year ago.  By switching to only backing up to locally connected SSD drives, I was able to knock mdsync run times down to around an hour.  But run times for mdsync (on SSD storage) have increased over the last year to the point where I am not back in the same situation that I was before - i.e. the Mac never goes to sleep because mdsync is always running.  I can no longer "fix" the problem by throwing higher speed storage at it.

Any ideas on how to tame the unruly mdsync would be appreciated.

Comment: Just at first glance, this sounds like you're taking a TM backup of a TM backup, of a TM backup of a system.  The problem here is your first backup is continually changing thus the never-ending sync of the sub-processes.  The second issue here is there's no [data resiliency](https://www.isaca.org/resources/isaca-journal/issues/2021/volume-3/data-resilience-is-data-risk-management). In other words, data recovery fails anywhere in this chain, you've lost everything.  I would start at the basics to ensure you; data is good, then start looking for ways to imporove it's uptime availablity,

Comment: Allan, I am not sure how you concluded that I am taking a TM of a TM of a TM.  But that is not what is happening.  It just a regular TM of a system.  The mdsync process runs whenever a disk is attached.  I should probably re-write my question to make it clearer that the problem is mdsync running on the contents of TM storage devices.